# Mysql Cluster error when storing data

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

I am facing following exception,

```
com.mysql.clusterj.ClusterJDatastoreException: Datastore exception. Return code: -1 Error code: 1,234 MySQL code: -1 Status: 1 Classification: 7 Message: bucket_storage2
```

Which parameter in config.ini i need to configure to get rid of it.

System Information:
Linux amp-sql1 2.6.18-371.el5 #1 SMP Thu Sep 5 21:21:44 EDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
config.ini parameters:

```
   DataMemory=8G
    DiskCheckpointSpeed=10M  
    FragmentLogFileSize=42M
    IndexMemory=768MB
    NoOfFragmentLogFiles=200
    NoOfReplicas=2
    MaxNoOfAttributes=1000  
    MaxNoOfConcurrentIndexOperations=500000
    MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations=500000
    MaxNoOfConcurrentTransactions=450000
    MaxNoOfExecutionThreads=4
    MaxNoOfLocalOperations=550000
    MaxNoOfOrderedIndexes=128  
    MaxNoOfSubscribers=0
    MaxNoOfTriggers=128  
    MaxNoOfTables=128  
    MaxNoOfUniqueHashIndexes=128   
    Odirect=1
    RedoBuffer=512M
    SharedGlobalMemory=256M
    TransactionBufferMemory=32M
    TransactionDeadlockDetectionTimeout=15000
    TransactionInactiveTimeout=60000
```

Two node cluster cluster , each node having 16GB physical RAM. Management node is deployed on different server
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you give us more info about the system this is happening on?

Comment: Please see my added information.